# How do you handle data grid cell changes with MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out how to handle changes in a data grid cell while keeping within the MVVM design pattern. When the user changes the value in a cell, I have to go off and change a bunch of files based on the new cell value. I know how I could easily do this with code behind, but is there a cleaner, more MVVM-esque way to do this with command bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your `DataGrid`'s`ItemsSource` is bound, `TwoWay`-mode, to something in your `ViewModel`, let's call it `CustomObject` or whatever.

Let's assume then that a specific `DataGridCell` is bound to a Property named `SomeProperty`, which is declared as follows:

```
private string someProperty;
public string SomeProperty {
  get { return someProperty; }
  set {
    someProperty = value;
    //Fire OnPropertyChanged here
  }
}
```

Put a breakpoint just on the set. Then, modify the cell in your View : the breakpoint will be reached.

This allows you to simulate an event: each time the set is called, it means the cell is gonna change, do whatever you want now with the changing process (you can for example test the new value, by testing on `value`, or keep the last value, by saving `someProperty` somewhere before the line `someProperty = value;` )

Comment: This does not look a proper way to do to me. Typically, grid will be bind to some collection object from ViewModel, and the 'CustomObject' will be defined in your Model. You can not do such operations there. 
Also, User edit is not the only thing which will change model object properties.

Answer (score 15):

Usually i do this with interaction triggers from Galasoft.

```
 <DataGrid IsReadOnly="False">
            <e:Interaction.Triggers>
                <e:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding CellEditEndingCommand}"/>
                </e:EventTrigger>
            </e:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
               ...                        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then inside ViewModel you create generic RelayCommand where generic type is type of corresponding EventArgs.

```
RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs> CellEditEndingCommand {get; set;}
```

Initialization:

```
CellEditEndingCommand = new RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(args=>DoSomething());
```

Comment: +1 because this is generally the way to do it, although you don't have to use Galasoft's version. PRISM also has a way to bind events to VM Commands, or you can find custom implentations such as http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/

Comment: Or you can create a DelegateCommand based on the CellEditEnding event