# How to get a focusable control inside a DataGridCell?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` and I'm subscribing to `PreparingCellForEdit`. On it there is a code that returns the `DataGridCell` by getting the element from keyboard focus.

```
var cell = Keyboard.FocusedElement as DataGridCell;
```

When I have the cell I need to find out if there is a focusable element inside it that is enabled, visible and editable.

Example:

```
 FieldX  |      FieldY
--------------------------
   [ ]+  |       [ ]+
   [ ]*  |  (not visible)

+ Enabled, visible, focusable
* IsEnabled = false
```

How can I find out if there is such an element inside the cell?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17000966/1997232). Why do you need that? Are you using [MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6358740/1997232)?

Comment: Yes and no, well, I don't have full freedom on this code I have to workaround it. Any major changes could impact on several other screens so I want to minimize the risk at this moment. I will have a look on that question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `VisualTreeHelper` to traverse through the child elements and then check if these elements fulfill your requirements. Something like this:

```
var elementList = new List<DependencyObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
{
    var element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
    if ((Visibility)element.GetValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty) == Visibility.Visible)
        elementList.Add(element);
}
```